# query created_at date only equals to carbon::now() date only in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to do you query created_at date only equals to Carbon::now() date only in laravel query builder.?

```
App\Table::where('created_at', '=' ,Carbon/Carbon:now() )->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can opt for the following kind of construct:

`App\Table::whereDate('created_at', '=', now()->toDateString())->get();`

Comment: it would work on `'>='`.  but not what im looking for. is there any magic function where you can get the created_at date only just like the raw `Date(created_at)` sql. `select * from table where Date(created_at) = '2019-12-18'`

Comment: @JuliusLimson `whereDate` should functionally be providing what you are looking for

Comment: @lagbox my bad, i didn't notice the `whereDate` function. thank you for pointing it out. thisi s what im looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mysql's` default `CURDATE` function with laravel query builder's Raw sql.

`DB::table('posts')->select(DB::raw('*'))
                  ->whereRaw('Date(created_at) = CURDATE()')->get();`

Or

`App\Table::where('created_at', '=', Carbon::today())`

Comment: i wish we can write it like this `App\Table::where('Date(created_at)', '=', Carbon::today())`.  the 2nd query is way more shorter and simple but only works if we change the oporator into `'>='`.

Answer (score 1):

No Need to use anything just check whereDate For Date

```
App\Table::whereDate('created_at', '=' ,Carbon/Carbon:now() )->get();
```

among this whereMonth for Month and whereDay for date

check this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#whereDate%20/%20whereMonth%20/%20whereDay%20/%20whereYear%20/%20whereTime